# Как изменить цвет текста путем выбора?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Здравствуйте. Нужно изменить цвет текста. Есть у меня поле `select` с определенными цветами. Например,

```
<select class="colorse">
<option style="background:#ffffff;" value="0">Белый</option>
<option style="background:#000000; color: #fff;" value="1">Черный</option>
</select>
```

Я так понимаю что без JS тут не обойтись. Помогите, пожалуйста. Цвет нужно изменить в теге `<span></span>`

Comment: Что именно не работает у Вас?

Comment: Я не знаю, как правильно оформить строку изменения цвета текста.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

самый простой вариант таков, но он вряд ли будет полезен в реальной задаче

```css
body {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<select class="colorse" onchange="getElementById('color-me').style.color = this.value;">
  <option style="background:#ffffff;" value="white">Белый</option>
  <option style="background:#000000; color: #fff;" value="black">Черный</option>
</select>


<span id="color-me">текст текст текст</span>
```

Comment: Мне нужно вынести это в span